# Limit of Recursive Sequence $y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{1}{ny_n}$ with $y_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I came up with this sequence as I was playing around with another question on this site. And so I decided to ask the users if they can find a solution.

Let $$y_1=1$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{1}{ny_n}.$$

Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} y_n \leq \infty.$$

Comment: Is this kind of challenge? :)

Comment: No, why ? I guess that kind of depends on how hard it turns out to be :)

Comment: I thought that you've solved already and found it interesting so you're sharing it with the community. Never Mind :)

Comment: @JaideepKhare No, I havent solved it, I dont even know if the limit is finite. I have played with it some, but I want to move on to other maths, and people here like these type questions, I think, so its just natural to see if someone else want to have crack at it. Its not totally trivial, (unless I missed something obvious).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence diverges.

Suppose the sequence was bounded by some constant, i.e. $y_n < C$ for all $n$. Then in particular $\frac{1}{y_n} > \frac{1}{C}$ for all $n$ so:

$y_{2}>y_1 + \frac{1}{C}$

$y_{3} > y_2 + \frac{1}{2C} > y_1 + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{2C}$

$y_{4} > y_3 + \frac{1}{3C} > y_1 + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{2C} + \frac{1}
{3C}$

...

$y_{n+1} > y_1 + \frac{1}{C} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$

But the harmonic series diverges.

EDIT:

I'd like to expand a bit on the exact asymptotics in response to Did's comment:

Using the same trick as above but with the squares:

$y_2^2 = y_1^2+\frac{2}{1}+\frac{1}{y_1^2}$

$y_3^2 = y_2^2+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{1}{4y_2^2} = y_1^2+(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{2}{2}) +(\frac{1}{y_1^2} + \frac{1}{4y_2^2})$

... (i.e. by induction)

$y_{n+1} = y_1^2 + 2(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}) + (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2y_i^2})$

$2H_n + 1 < y_{n+1}^2 < 2H_n + 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Where in the last step we use that $y_n \ge 1$ for all $n$ and the sum of the reciprocals of squares sums to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  So indeed $y_n \approx \sqrt{2H_n}$, as suggested.

Comment: And the exact asymptotics might be $$y_n\sim\sqrt{2H_n}$$

Comment: A strength of the approach in this post is that it can be generalized. For example, if $$y_{n+1}=y_n+x_ng(y_n)$$ for every $n$, for some nonnegative sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\sum x_n$ diverges, and for some continuous function $g$ positive on $[y_0,+\infty)$, then $$y_n\to\infty$$